# no-unused-var eslint for modules and types in nestsjs

Tags: node.js, eslint, nestjs, tslint

I have added eslint to my nestjs 7 projects and got confused with the unused vars error

I got errors on Modules, lifecycle method, and services.
also got errors of types

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  HealthCheck,
  HealthCheckService,  ---> got here the the error
  MongooseHealthIndicator, ---> got here the  the error
} from '@nestjs/terminus';

@Controller('health')
export class HealthController {
  constructor(
    private health: HealthCheckService,
    private mongoose: MongooseHealthIndicator
  ) {}

  @Get()
  @HealthCheck()
  check() {
    return this.health.check([() => this.mongoose.pingCheck('mongoose')]);
  }
}
```

elintrc.js configuration :

```
module.exports = {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
    extends: [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    ],
    env: {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    overrides: [
        {
            "files": ["*.js"],
            "rules": {
                "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this comes from [this issue in typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2559). Only workaround currently is to not use that specific rule.